# Pandas sum includes column headers

Tags: python, pandas, sum

### Background

I have a dataset of about 200 countries (rows) for different time periods (columns). The Pandas dataframe of this dataset is as follows:

```py
data = {'Country': ['Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Algeria', 'Andorra', 'Angola'],
        '1958-1962': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        '2008-2012': [0.0, 0.0, 8.425, 0.0, 0.0],
        '2013-2017': [0.0, 0.0, 10.46, 0.0, 0.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

     Country  1958-1962  2008-2012  2013-2017
 Afghanistan          0      0.000       0.00
     Albania          0      0.000       0.00
     Algeria          0      8.425      10.46
     Andorra          0      0.000       0.00
      Angola          0      0.000       0.00
```

I am trying to obtain sum of all the values in each column using the following code.

```
y_data = []

period_list = list(df)
period_list.remove('Country')

for x in period_list:
    y_data.append(df[x].sum())
```

### Error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

For some reason, Pandas is also including the header in the sum process. How do I resolve this?

### Other tests

I tested the sum function on the following dataframe using `df.sum()` , and it appropriately produced the sum of numbers for each column as 18, 20, 20, 19.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[5, 3, 6, 4], 
                   "B":[11, 2, 4, 3], 
                   "C":[4, 3, 8, 5], 
                   "D":[5, 4, 2, 8]})
```

The output of `print(df.drop("Country",axis=1).dtypes)` is as follows:

```
1958-1962    object
1963-1967    object
1968-1972    object
1973-1977    object
1978-1982    object
1983-1987    object
1988-1992    object
1993-1997    object
1998-2002    object
2003-2007    object
2008-2012    object
2013-2017    object
dtype: object
```

### Solution

I used `df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')` to convert the objects into numbers and that resolved the issue.

Comment: check `df.drop("Country",axis=1).dtypes` if any column name returns `object` it means that column has a string value, look at `pd.to_numeric` to handle set the strings to `NaN` and then sum

Comment: `df.sum()` works just fine for `axis=1` or `axis=0`. That loop implementation is not the correct way to sum columns of a dataframe though. If you sum a column a strings, sum will join all the strings.  Check the `dtypes` of your numeric columns.

Comment: Just `set_index` to `Country` first, i.e. `df.set_index("Country").sum()`

Comment: @anky I have edited the question to include the output and it says object.

Comment: `df.set_index("Country").apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').sum(1)` ? for countrywise sum or `df.set_index("Country").apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').sum()` for datewise sum..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the columns you want to sum from objects to numeric and then drop Country column before making sum in the rest of columns.

Refer this link for [converting from object to numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html)